# Why is TFS asking to resolve conflict after get specific version

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I am downloading a specific version of a branch but keep getting prompted to resolve conflicts after the download is complete.

Before I call get specific version, the state of the branch is "not downloaded", I confirmed this with file explorer, the folder does not exit locally .
I have also checked `Overwrite writable files that are not checked out` and `Overwrite all files even if that local version matches the specific version` in the get specific version Get dialog.

If no local files existed before the call to get specific version what is the server version conflicting with?

Surly any conflicts would have been resolved when that change set was initially commit-ed, the change set cannot be in a conflicted state on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the mapping from the root directory and then adding it back again solved this. There must have been a conflict between the actual files and what VS thought was there.
Still don't know why it would try to merge in that situation though. Surly the state of the actual folder should take prescience over whatever VS thought was in there.

Comment: if you used a local workspace it would, if you were using a server workspace you'd experience the behavior you did